# Wordpress MU - Error 500 when url does not exist from wp-content

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, server, url-routing, multisite

Configuration :
Wordpress MU
Wordpress version 5.2.3
Some plugins (Yoast, WpRocket, Statistcs, CF7, Duplicator, NSsiteCopier)
I have a big trouble with Wordpress MU. When bad URL is requested from. 
https://mycustomurl/wp-content/**foldernotexist**  = error 500
https://mycustomurl/wp-admin/**foldernotexist**  = error 500
All requests with wordpress native folder (actually wp-content is my trouble) give me a 500 error.
I rename wp-content/plugins_ (to identify plugin issue) wp-content/themes_ (to identify theme issue)
Same result = error 500

Here it my basic .htaccess (i remove WPRocket / Itheme security and all redirection for this test)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Here it is my wp-config.php

```
<?php define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true ); 
// Redirect All HTTP Page Requests to HTTPS - Security > Settings > Secure Socket Layers (SSL) > SSL for Dashboard define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by WP Rocket define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true); // Added by Sysnove 2019-06-25 define('DB_NAME', 'mycustomdbname');
define('DB_USER', 'mycustomuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mycustompassword');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
*/
define('AUTH_KEY',         'saltcode');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'saltcode');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'saltcode');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'saltcode');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'saltcode');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'saltcode');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'saltcode');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'saltcode');

define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true); 
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '/multisites.mycustomdomain.fr/');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )  define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . 
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Do you have some tips ? Maybe i miss something ? 
I try all i find over the WEB to identify trouble. All io can say, it's when u put inexistent folders and URL contained wp-content.

I ask help for 2 reasons : this issue generates more than 15 Go of logs every day... and About SEO, 500 is not interesting, 404 is more SEO Friendly.

Regards,

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://mycustomurl/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/bb-plugin/cache/389-layout.css


in this cached CSS, i can read two request about bad url when we clone already made website :

(https://multisites.customurl.com/mu-cloned-url-referer--2/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2016/09/01_Home_05.jpg)


I ask more log to identify various profile or request.
Cheer

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the permissions for the wp-content folder and its subdirectories are set correctly. Typically, they should be set to 755 for directories and 644 for files. Incorrect permissions could result in a 500 error.